# How to print python code after decorators are applied?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand a complex python decorator and I'd like to see the resulting python code *after* the decorator has been applied, i.e. the actual python code for the wrapped function once python has applied the decorator. Is this possible?

I thought I could do this with inspect but didn't get the result I expected. I tried putting the code in a module, importing it then using `print(inspect.getsource(module_name))`, but this prints the original source code with the `@decorator`, not the wrapped functions after decorators applied.

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")

say_whee()
```

The above produces a result similar to code below before python runs it. I'd like to see the code for resulting function after the decorator above has been applied

```
def say_whee2():
    print("Whee!")

def say_whee_decorated():
    print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
    say_whee2()
    print("Something is happening after the function is called.")

say_whee_decorated()
```

I expected to see something like `say_whee_decorated()` as a result of `inspect.getsource()` but instead, got:

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")
```

Comment: You can use `inspect.getsource(say_whee)` after it has been decorated; since the decorator returns the wrapper function, it will return the source of `wrapper()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're after but I think you're misunderstanding the nature of decorators (and of inspect.getsource()), they don't create new code to wrap the function, they just pass the decorated function into the decorating one and execute it, there is no intermediate code created so you shouldn't expect to see any.